# CNContactViewController Cancel Button Not Working in iOS 13

Tags: ios, contacts-framework

The `CANCEL` button has no effect when presenting a `CNContactViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`.

Whenever we click on `CANCEL` Button on `ContactViewcontroller`, **CNContactViewControllerDeligate
method not called** in iOS **13**

Comment: did you set your delegate correctly, please share bunch of code for your work

Comment: did you set your delegate correctly - YES and @interface ViewController : UIViewController<CNContactPickerDelegate,CNContactViewControllerDelegate>

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: no, it works, just fine, you have to make sure your'e calling the delegate, link your code, hten i'll post the asnwer

Comment: ABNewPersonViewController *c = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
        [c setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];     
                                                                                                                                [c setDisplayedPerson:person];                                                                         
        [c setEditing:NO];
        CFRelease(person);

Comment: did you find any solution ?